# Help with AVR ADC and Serial port programming and integrating with python

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, adc, avr, 7segmentdisplay

I am a 2nd year electrical engineering student. I was stuck at this: Why do both seven segment displays show only 8 even when simulation is not running?
Basically I am trying to take temperature data from LM35 sensor into Atmega16 via ADC, then I am trying to output the value on seven segment displays.
Later on I also have to use python to make or send commands to microcontroller. I also have to use matplotlib.  It is requested to explain what to do?
[image]
Here is the C code for this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <xc.h>

unsigned char currentvoltage;
unsigned char voltageafterfilter;
unsigned char voltage_array[4];

char SevenSegment (unsigned char number  )
{ // a b c d e f g
    if ( number == '0' ) return 0x01 ; // 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 a
    else if ( number == '1' ) return 0x40 ; // 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ?????
    else if ( number == '2' ) return 0x12 ; // 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 f | | b
    else if ( number == '3' )return 0x06 ; // 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 | g |
    else if ( number == '4' )return 0x4C ; // 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 ?????
    else if ( number == '5' ) return 0x24 ; // 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 e | | c
    else if ( number == '6' )return 0x20 ; // 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 | |
    else if ( number == '7' ) return 0x0F ; // 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ?????
    else if ( number == '8' ) return 0x00 ; // 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 d
    else if ( number == '9' ) return 0x0C ; // 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    else return 0xFF ;
}
void adc_init()
{
    // AREF = AVcc
    ADMUX = (1 << REFS0);
    //Setting ADLAR to 1 to left align/left shift
    ADMUX = (1 << ADLAR);
    // ADC Enable and prescaler of 128
    ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);
}
// read adc value
void adc_read(uint8_t ch)
{   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    // select the corresponding channel 0~7
    ch &= 0b00000111;  // AND operation with 7
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF8)|ch;
    // start single conversion
    // write '1' to ADSC to start conversion:
    ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);
    // wait for conversion to complete:
    while((ADCSRA & (1 << ADSC)) != 0);
    
    
    currentvoltage = ADCH;
    voltage_array[i] = currentvoltage;
    }
    
    //Once all 4 voltage samples are taken preprocessing is done:
    preprocessing();
    PORTB = SevenSegment(voltageafterfilter);
}

// f u n c ti o n t o i n i t i a l i z e UART communication
void UART_initializer()
{
    UBRRL = 0xC ; // s e t baud r a t e t o 4800
    UCSRB |= (1<<RXEN) ; // e n a bl e t r a n smi t t e r
    UCSRC |= (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ0)|(1<<UCSZ1) ; // s e t data s i z e
}

// f u n c ti o n t o t r a n smi t data o ve r UART
void UART_receive ( )
{
    while ( ! ( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE) ) ) ; // p o l l UDRE and w ai t t o r e c e i v e data
    unsigned char val = UDR;
    
}

void preprocessing()
{
    
    voltageafterfilter = (voltage_array[3] + voltage_array[2] + voltage_array[1] + voltage_array[0])/4;
    
}

void minmax()
{
    
}

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    adc_read(0);
    
}


int main(void)
{
    
    //Initializing timer1:
    TCNT1 = 0;
    
    //Configuring portb and portc for output:
    DDRB = 0xFF;
    DDRC = 0xFF;
    //vALUE OF ocr1a, which was found after solving with prescalar of 64 15625 - 1 = 15624:
    OCR1A = 15624;
    //Configuring timer A to be in CTC mode with prescalar 64:
    TCCR1A = 0x00;
    TCCR1B = 0x0B;
    sei();
    adc_init();
    while(1)
    {
      
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Why do both seven segment displays show only 8 even when simulation is not running?"* Is that your only question? If so, most of your information is irrelevant and the answer is probably simply that when not running a simulation, Proteus displays a generic symbol that clearly shows a 7 segment display (with all segments active).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you were to physically build this then you'll need to remember to add some resistors between the displays and the micro.

Comment: I am curious why should resistors be added between micro and displays? Is it just to be safe? Also how to find that which value of resistors is the correct value for the case?

Comment: @Talha Because LEDs can not be driven with voltage. Without resistors, too much current flows and it can burn out the LED immediately or damage IO pins of the MCU. In circuit simulators you can abuse the parts and they do not damage, break, start smoking or explode, but in real life circuits they do that. But otherwise, there are just too many separate questions, and there must be tutorials how to do serial programming in Python and that does not relate to electronics.

Answer (score 0):

Your display function expects ASCII characters, but you are giving it integer values from the ADC. Note that `'0' == 48` in ASCII.

You will need to convert the ADC values to their string representation first.

Comment: Why bother converting to string first, as that's more complex than just taking ones and tens out of a variable, so that string step can be omitted.

Comment: @Justme sure, that's a valid way of converting to a string representation.